# QTemporaryFile with sensitive contents (no physical file)

Tags: qt, temporary-files

I want to call an external process (`diff`) on two strings which are a bit sensitive (not *very* critical). This is why I don't want to store them as files on the disc unencrypted.  However, `diff` only accepts file names (well, one of the two files can be the standard input but this doesn't really help me).

So I had the idea to write the data to a `QTemporaryFile` which automatically deletes the file when running out of scope. Depending on the platform and configuration, a `QTemporaryFile` will be stored in RAM only. However, since there is no guarantee about that, I had the idea to *safely delete* the file by zero-ing the contents before deletion. I don't need the files hidden from other processes while `diff` is running (I'm not that pedantic), but I don't want any process to be able to read the file *afterwards*.

Is my idea the correct approach here? Do you know a different way to invoke `diff` by not using files?

Maybe there is a portable way to go through named pipes? (I only know `mkfifo` on UNIXoid systems). Maybe Qt even has some solution for this? When googling, I only found `QLocalSocket` which doesn't seem to be the right choice.

I need the solution to be portable, especially I want to support Linux and Windows 7; please consider this when pointing me to some native solution.

Comment: will you ship your own diff (especially on Windows), or what makes you think using diff is a portable solution? Depending on what exactly you need from diff, you might consider using in-process code to do the comparisons.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld Can't `diff` be built on Windows? By now I expected that this will be no problem at all; I think it shouldn't depend on system-dependent stuff. (But I don't know and didn't try it yet.) Maybe it is a good solution to embed `diff` within my application, good idea.